# how can i change the index to change it to get the value you want?

Tags: python, list

```
rainbow = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

index = rainbow.index(4)
rainbow[index] = "blue"
print(rainbow)
```

I want to change it to get the color blue

Comment: That would depend, in part, on what language this is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Python:
This `index = rainbow.index(4)` shoulnd't work. Although I am not very sure what you are looking for as the question is stated right now.

```
rainbow = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

index = rainbow.index("blue") # Get the index in where "blue" is in the list
print(index)
print(rainbow[index])
```

Print results:

```
4
blue
```

You can always do a for loop, and check the current element, if it is the value, get the count done until getting there. But with `index`, it is pretty straightforward.